# Small left panel - float not working fine HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm working on layout and I have small problem. I have left panel (block element) and other site content. When content in right site of page don't have many signs I'm using on this parent `float:right` and it's working. When I have big peace of text everything it's crached. Under you can see my page when I remove `float:right`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldkqj.png

Left panel has `float:left`. How can I separate this content like that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/maLZH.png

I'm trying to use `display:inline-block` but it's not working.

Structure of my file:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left-panel">
    <!-- LEFT PANEL -->
  </div>
  <div id="right-panel">
    <!-- RIGHT CONTENT -->
  </div>
</div>
```

My code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uuz2b8mr/

Comment: Why not you provide fiddle in such case?

Comment: I add code to jsfiddle if it will help

Comment: You can add `float:left` in `right-panel` as well. whats problem with that?

Comment: When I add `float:left` to right-panel (in my code is inside) this not work: http://i.imgur.com/Xx7In8i.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve that issues in a couple of methods:

**Method 1** - Fixed width for both columns

- basically set a fixed width for both columns, and their combined width would be the width of the parent:
- eg: .left-col: width: 25%; right-col: width 75%; (also some float may be required)

```css
.left-col {
  width: 25%;
  background: blue;
  
  float: left;
}
.right-col {
  width: 75%;
  background: yellow;
  
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-col">here be: the sidebar</div>
<div class="right-col">here be: a bunch of stuff Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ornare et velit a accumsan. Sed sed venenatis tortor. Morbi accumsan, ante sed laoreet varius, est purus euismod dolor, ut laoreet magna neque nec felis. Morbi
  vestibulum metus eget nibh viverra, et bibendum ex hendrerit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris sollicitudin, est nec placerat ornare, purus justo consectetur diam, vitae ultrices urna nisl
  eu ante. Integer sed ipsum gravida, posuere arcu eu, posuere tortor. Integer porttitor maximus tincidunt. Duis viverra risus ac gravida vehicula. Cras sagittis velit a dolor finibus venenatis in a magna. Maecenas consequat velit mauris, nec tempus nulla
  lacinia sit amet. Phasellus libero ante, elementum eget diam id, ultrices tincidunt ante. Integer id interdum urna, vel dignissim elit. Ut tincidunt, nisi vel interdum auctor, nisi velit aliquet tortor, eu viverra risus magna eu urna. Nulla et sodales
  sem. Ut tincidunt nibh eu dolor feugiat vehicula. Curabitur ac vestibulum sem. Nunc nec congue mi, tristique iaculis odio. Curabitur commodo tellus mi, vitae pellentesque metus porttitor nec. In rhoncus dolor a lorem lobortis sollicitudin.</div>
```

**Method 2** - Float the sidebar, overflow the content

- here the sidebar is floated;
- the content has a `display: block` applied to it, and a `overflow: hidden` rule, that will push the content to the left/right depending on its sibling float and width props.;
- you don't need any fixed widths for this to work, however one of those tags has to floated

```css
.left-col{
  float: left;
  background: blue;
}
.right-col{
  display: block; /*may or may not be necesary depending on ur tag*/
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-col">here be: the sidebar</div>
<div class="right-col">here be: a bunch of stuffLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ornare et velit a accumsan. Sed sed venenatis tortor. Morbi accumsan, ante sed laoreet varius, est purus euismod dolor, ut laoreet magna neque nec felis. Morbi
  vestibulum metus eget nibh viverra, et bibendum ex hendrerit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris sollicitudin, est nec placerat ornare, purus justo consectetur diam, vitae ultrices urna nisl
  eu ante. Integer sed ipsum gravida, posuere arcu eu, posuere tortor. Integer porttitor maximus tincidunt. Duis viverra risus ac gravida vehicula. Cras sagittis velit a dolor finibus venenatis in a magna. Maecenas consequat velit mauris, nec tempus nulla
  lacinia sit amet. Phasellus libero ante, elementum eget diam id, ultrices tincidunt ante. Integer id interdum urna, vel dignissim elit. Ut tincidunt, nisi vel interdum auctor, nisi velit aliquet tortor, eu viverra risus magna eu urna. Nulla et sodales
  sem. Ut tincidunt nibh eu dolor feugiat vehicula. Curabitur ac vestibulum sem. Nunc nec congue mi, tristique iaculis odio. Curabitur commodo tellus mi, vitae pellentesque metus porttitor nec. In rhoncus dolor a lorem lobortis sollicitudin.</div>
```

**Method 3** - The table trick

- This one requires some kind of wrapper that will hold both the sidebar and the content;
- the wrapper has a `display: table` applied to it, and both the sidebar and the content have `display: table-cell` applied;
- You may need to play around with some extra wrappers inside both the sidebar and the content, as both will stretch to which one is longer, in case you have some sort of a bg-color applied to one of them
- No fixed widths required

```css
.left-content,
.right-content{
  display: table-cell;
}
.left-content{
  background: blue;
}
.right-content{
  background: yellow;
}
.content-wrapper{
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="left-content">
    here be: the sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="right-content">
    here be: a bunch of stuff Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ornare et velit a accumsan. Sed sed venenatis tortor. Morbi accumsan, ante sed laoreet varius, est purus euismod dolor, ut laoreet magna neque nec felis. Morbi vestibulum metus eget nibh viverra, et bibendum ex hendrerit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris sollicitudin, est nec placerat ornare, purus justo consectetur diam, vitae ultrices urna nisl eu ante. Integer sed ipsum gravida, posuere arcu eu, posuere tortor. Integer porttitor maximus tincidunt. Duis viverra risus ac gravida vehicula.

Cras sagittis velit a dolor finibus venenatis in a magna. Maecenas consequat velit mauris, nec tempus nulla lacinia sit amet. Phasellus libero ante, elementum eget diam id, ultrices tincidunt ante. Integer id interdum urna, vel dignissim elit. Ut tincidunt, nisi vel interdum auctor, nisi velit aliquet tortor, eu viverra risus magna eu urna. Nulla et sodales sem. Ut tincidunt nibh eu dolor feugiat vehicula. Curabitur ac vestibulum sem. Nunc nec congue mi, tristique iaculis odio. Curabitur commodo tellus mi, vitae pellentesque metus porttitor nec. In rhoncus dolor a lorem lobortis sollicitudin.
  </div>
</div>
```

**Method 4** - Flexbox

- This one is pretty new, however its been rapidly adopted by new browsers, and may be helpful depending on ur scenarion
- Basically a wrapper holds both the sidebar and the content, and has display: flex applied to it(also some vendor prefixes may be required)
- No fixed widths required
- A more comprehensive guide can be found **[here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

```css
.content-wrapper {
 display: flex;
}

.left-col {
  min-width: 100px;/*may be necesarry depending or ur layout*/
  background: blue;
}

.right-col{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="left-col">here be the sidebar</div>
  <div class="right-col">here be the content metus eget nibh viverra, et bibendum ex hendrerit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris sollicitudin, est nec placerat ornare, purus justo consectetur diam, vitae ultrices urna nisl eu ante. Integer sed ipsum gravida, posuere arcu eu, posuere tortor. Integer porttitor maximus tincidunt. Duis viverra risus ac gravida vehicula.

Cras sagittis velit a dolor finibus venenatis in a magna. Maecenas consequat velit mauris, nec tempus nulla lacinia sit amet. Phasellus libero ante, elementum eget diam id, ultrices tincidunt ante. Integer id interdum urna, vel dignissim elit. Ut tincidunt, nisi vel interdum auctor, nisi velit aliquet tortor, eu viverra risus magna eu urna. Nulla et sodales sem. Ut tincidunt nibh eu dolor fe</div>
</div>
```

I'm pretty sure that there are some more versatile solutions out there, but hopefully this will get you goinn.

Comment: No problem-o, glad to help out!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
}

.left-panel{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: (your width)
}

.right-panel{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left: (your sidebar width)
}
```

Comment: What is sidebar width is variable? I have two language versions - so content in left panel is changing. :)

Comment: In that case I'd suggest using a flex box solution, however adopting a fixed width would make things easier for you in regards to browser support.

Comment: I can do it with fixed width :) but I can't